# How to save input data from terminal into a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to save input data from the terminal in a CSV file. Here is the code

```py
import csv

field = ['Account', 'Name']
rows = []
filename = "db.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(field)
    while True:
        acc = int(input("Account No: "))
        name = input("Enter Name: ")
        rows[0] = acc
        rows[1] = name
    # writing the data rows
        csvwriter.writerows(rows)
        break
```

How to save those data in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import csv

field = ['Account', 'Name']
rows = []
filename = "db.csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(field)
    while True:
        acc = int(input("Account No: "))
        name = input("Enter Name: ")
        # writing the data rows
        csvwriter.writerow([acc, name])
        keep_going = input("Continue? [y/n]")
        if keep_going.lower() == "n":
            break
```

Comment: Give a programmer some code, you save his butt for a day. Teach a programmer how to code, he can save his own damn butt in the future instead of asking trivial questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I thought it was close enough to his code to not need any extra explanations, but you're right

Answer (score 1):

`rows` is an empty list you can't use `rows[0]` and `rows[1]` like this.

You can use `append()` method

```
rows.append(acc)
rows.append(name)
csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

or simply

```
csvwriter.writerows([acc, name])
```